# Cannot ftp push files to AWS using grunt

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, ftp, gruntjs

I have a grunt task `ftp_push` which deploys my files to an Ubuntu 14.04 AWS instance. The task is given below.

> ```
>     ftp_push: {
>   src: {
>     options: {
>       host: "HOST_IP",
>       username: "USER_NAME",
>       password: "PASSWORD",
>       dest: "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/test",
>     },
>     files: [
>       {
>         expand: true,
>         cwd: 'src',
>         src: [
>           "app/**",
>           "assets/**",
>           ".htaccess",
>           "404.html",
>           "icon.ico",
>           "my.html",
>           "new.txt"
>         ]
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> }
> });
> ```

But when I run this task all folders and subfolders are getting created. But no files are getting deployed to the specified path.Even the `new.txt ,my.html` etc are also not deployed. Please help me out.

Authencation is successful. I used VSFTPD